# 'initializing': cannot convert from 'EVENTLOGRECORD *' to 'EVENTLOGRECORD []'

Tags: c++, winapi

when i try to create an array:

`EVENTLOGRECORD logs[] = new EVENTLOGRECORD[dwEventLogRecords];`

it gives the error 'conversion' : cannot convert from 'type1' to 'type2' i don't know how to fix this please help.

```
#include <Windows.h>

void main() {
    DWORD dwEventLogRecords;
    HANDLE hEventLog = OpenEventLogA(0,"System");
    GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(hEventLog, &dwEventLogRecords);
    int numberOfBytes = sizeof(EVENTLOGRECORD)*dwEventLogRecords;
    EVENTLOGRECORD logs[] = new EVENTLOGRECORD[dwEventLogRecords];
    ReadEventLog(hEventLog, EVENTLOG_SEEK_READ | EVENTLOG_FORWARDS_READ,0,logs, numberOfBytes, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: `EVENTLOGRECORD logs[] = new EVENTLOGRECORD[dwEventLogRecords];` should be `EVENTLOGRECORD *logs = new EVENTLOGRECORD[dwEventLogRecords];`

Comment: yes but i want an array not a pointer

Comment: You'll get a pointer pointing to the array you want.

Comment: You can't initialize an array from a pointer. `new[]` returns a pointer. You have to store the result to a pointer variable. You can still access the array elements using array-like syntax via `[]`.

Comment: how come it works for ints e.g. int logs[] = new int[10]; ??????

Comment: Which compiler do you use? `int logs[] = new int[10];` will also get the error "'initializing': cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int []'" in my vs2017.

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit conversion from pointers to array types in C++. They are similar, but not identical. Arrays can decay to pointers, but it doesn't work the other way round as information is lost on the way - a pointer just represents a memory address, while an array represents the address of a continuous region, typically with a particular size.

I suggest to read section 6 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Furthermore,

```
type *a and type b[]
```

`a` is a variable that needs to allocate memory space for storage, while `b` is a label in the program that provides address information to the compiler without saving. So you can change `a` in the program, but you can't change `b` which is unmodifiable.